# Parse.com: How do you get the current user on a Node.js server running locally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, express, parse-platform

I'm using Parse's FacebookUtils to authenticate my users client side. Once a user is logged in, is it possible to get the current user on the server side using a session cookie in the request header? I did notice there's a sessions table in Parse Data. I'm running my own express server and my middleware looks something like this:

```
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Cookies: ", req.cookies);
  res.type('html');
  res.write('hello world');
  res.end();
});
```